# code explanation for glibc "login_tty()" function: "open(ttyname)" immediately followed by "close()"

Tags: c, linux, glibc, tty, pts

I was reading the glibc code, specifically the login_tty function, and I found a piece of code that did not make much sense to me:

```
newfd = open (fdname, O_RDWR);
(void) close (newfd);
```

this opens a file and closes it immediately, I want to know why

[complete function code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=login/login_tty.c;h=a94f5cb861d1b36ac6004e523ef50806d0fcedc1;hb=HEAD):

```
int
login_tty (int fd)
{
        (void) setsid();
#ifdef TIOCSCTTY
        if (ioctl(fd, TIOCSCTTY, (char *)NULL) == -1)
                return (-1);
#else
        {
          /* This might work.  */
          char *fdname = ttyname (fd);
          int newfd;
          if (fdname)
            {
              if (fd != 0)
                (void) close (0);
              if (fd != 1)
                (void) close (1);
              if (fd != 2)
                (void) close (2);
              newfd = open (fdname, O_RDWR);
              (void) close (newfd);
            }
        }
#endif
        while (dup2(fd, 0) == -1 && errno == EBUSY)
          ;
        while (dup2(fd, 1) == -1 && errno == EBUSY)
          ;
        while (dup2(fd, 2) == -1 && errno == EBUSY)
          ;
        if (fd > 2)
                (void) close(fd);
        return (0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe a touch, i. e. set its file time to now?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with making `fd` the controlling terminal, as described [in the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/openpty.3.html), since that's what the `ioctl` call is attempting to do.

Comment: Please try to make your question self-contained, this includes citing all relevant code (as long as it's reasonably short) -- I did it for you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [APUE](http://www.apuebook.com/) (2nd edition, 2005), Section 9.6 - Controlling Terminal:

> POSIX.1 leaves the choice of the **mechanism used to allocate a controlling terminal** up to each
> individual implementation. We’ll show the actual steps in Section 19.4.
>
> **Systems derived from UNIX System V** allocate the controlling terminal for a session when the
> session leader **opens the first terminal device** that is not already associated with a session. This
> assumes that the call to `open` by the session leader does not specify the `O_NOCTTY` flag
> (Section 3.3).
>
> **BSD-based systems** allocate the controlling terminal for a session when the session leader **calls
> `ioctl` with a request argument of `TIOCSCTTY`** (the third argument is a null pointer). The
> session cannot already have a controlling terminal for this call to succeed. (Normally, this call
> to `ioctl` follows a call to `setsid`, which guarantees that the process is a session leader
> without a controlling terminal.) The POSIX.1 `O_NOCTTY` flag to open is not used by
> BSD-based systems, except in compatibility-mode support for other systems.

Answer (score 3):

I can't give a definitive answer, but it's somehow an attempt to make the terminal associated with `fd` the *controlling terminal* of the process.

If you have a look at the first alternative of the code, it uses an `ioctl`: `TIOCSCTTY`. This one is documented as "*Make the given terminal the controlling terminal of the calling process. [...]*", see for example [this manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl).

The code you don't understand is in the alternative part that's used if the `TIOCSCTTY` ioctl isn't available. I can only guess that, after closing all standard file descriptors (`0` to `2`), opening a file that's a tty might have the *side effect* to make it the controlling terminal.